# ¿Qué es estar en "números azules"?

Tags: significado, vocabulario-técnico, finanzas

Ayer leí esta expresión de estar en "números azules". En contexto, alguien decía que tras mucho esfuerzo y sacrificio, había logrado tener una empresa "con números azules", que entiendo que es "financieramente saneada" o "financieramente saludable".

Estar en "números rojos" es, como todos sabemos (y [citando al DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QiamBaG))

> 1. m. pl. Saldo negativo en una cuenta bancaria o en una contabilidad empresarial.

No sé por qué siempre asumí que si no estabas en "números rojos" los números eran negros, pero claro, "[en negro](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QN0nGts)" significa

> 1. loc. adv. coloq. Sin regularizar, fuera de la ley.

Buscando un poco por internet he encontrado algún post sobre estar en "números azules", pero no se explica claramente qué es lo que es, por lo que he pensado en hacer esta pregunta y que así quede de manera explícita en algún sitio.

¿Qué es estar en "números azules"? ¿Es lo contrario a estar en "números rojos" o es otra cosa distinta?

Comment: Interesante pregunta, nunca había oído hablar de números azules la verdad.

Comment: Creo que en inglés sí se usa "in the red/in the black" para indicar un balance negativo/positivo respectivamente. No sé si es igual en español o si por el contrario es "en rojo/en azul". A ver si alguien nos saca de dudas. Yo también tengo bastante curiosidad por esta. Como digo, no hay entradas en el DRAE para "números negros/azules" como sí hay para rojos, pero eso no significa que esas expresiones no se usen. Probablemente solo se usan menos y son más desconocidas. Quizá "en azul" es más que "en negro", no solo en positivo, sino con ciertas ganancias

Comment: Gracias. En los que yo he visto, como [Los números azules que quiere Sepomex](http://www.milenio.com/opinion/barbara-anderson/nada-personal-solo-negocios/los-numeros-azules-que-quiere-sepomex) me da a entender que "estar en números azules" no es simplemente lo opuesto a estar en rojo, si no que lo que tienes te da para ser financieramente independiente, funcionar y hacer cosas por cierto tiempo. Digamos que si mi empresa tiene un balance de $50, pues no estamos en rojo, pero con eso evidentemente no vamos a ningún lado. Estar en azul sería estar por encima de un cierto valor o porcentaje.

Comment: Nunca había leído la expresión esta de "los número azules". Según leí en algún sitio que no recuerdo, el origen de los "números rojos" es chino, porque éstos tradicionalmente escribían los valores negativos con tinta roja, al contrario que los positivos, que escribían con tinta negra.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yo lo he escuchado en varias ocasiones en el ámbito empresarial chileno significando que los resultados económicos de una empresa son positivos, que se obtienen ganancias.

Ejemplos en la prensa chilena:

> Luego de dos años de números en rojo, el informe financiero de la empresa arroja ganancias. Con relación al Model Y, se informó que su prototipo ya fue aprobado y que podría ser presentado a inicios del próximo año.

[Emol, diario electrónico chileno](https://www.emol.com/noticias/Autos/2018/10/25/925200/Tesla-festeja-numeros-azules-y-anuncia-que-en-marzo-proximo-presentara-el-Model-Y.html)

> Canal 13 se recupera de sus pérdidas históricas y vuelve a los números azules

[La Tercera, diario electrónico chileno](https://www.latercera.com/pulso/noticia/canal-13-se-recupera-perdidas-historicas-vuelve-los-numeros-azules/317566/)

Buscando en internet veo que se usa la expresión también en Perú, aparentemente más en el sentido que indica la pregunta, no solo entregando utilidades si no que con suficiente capital de trabajo para operar:

> ¿Cómo saber si una empresa está en "números azules"?
>
> Para mantenerse en marcha, una empresa debe alcanzar un adecuado nivel de capital de trabajo.

[https://www.esan.edu.pe/](https://www.esan.edu.pe/apuntes-empresariales/2017/08/como-saber-si-una-empresa-esta-en-numeros-azules/)

Comment: Agregando a esto, al menos en el colegio tenemos notas de 1-7, y las notas menores a 4 son reprobatorias, y se escriben con rojo en el libro de clases. Las notas normales se escriben con azul (lapices bic, azul y rojo).